# RIP Peter Mayhew - Chewbacca Actor

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Star Wars actor Peter Mayhew, who played Chewbacca in the original trilogy of films, has died at the age of 74.

**RIP**

[image]

Comment: He will tear many arms off in Wookie-heaven now.

Comment: Note that he also played Chewie in Revenge of the Sith, and shared the role with Joonas Suotamo in The Force Awakens.

Comment: @Angew - Indeed. And also in the Holiday Special and countless fan expos and cons

Comment: @Valorum... of that we do not speak, harrumph?! </Yoda>

Answer (score 51):

## AAARARRRGWWWH RRRAARRWHHGWWR!

Comment: That's very true. So true.

Answer (score 25):

[image: Chewbacca's Death, Dark Horse "Chewbacca #4"]

<sub>From Dark Horse's [*Chewbacca* issue 4](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chewbacca_4) (a Legends comic published in 2000, which reflected on the death of Chewbacca in that continuity)</sub>

Comment: Seeing Han Solo like this kills me

Answer (score 11):

He also played the metal minotaur in the Ray Harryhausen monster movie, *Sinbad and the Eye of the Tiger*.

[image: Sinbad and the Eye of the Tiger]

Much of the time, the minotaur was a miniature, but for long shots of the minotaur rowing Zenobia's boat, it was Mayhew in costume.

Answer (score 9):

He toured Johnson Space Center 9 years ago this March and got to fly the Shuttle Mission Simulator. And yes, the phrase "Punch it Chewie" was said on the loops.

Comment: But did he crash?

Comment: Everyone crashes the first time.

Comment: Odds were he would crash it. But nobody told them to him...

Answer (score 5):

## Rest in peace, Chewie

### You were the highlight of all of Star Wars.

Answer (score 3):

## RIP

[image]